# Call Multiple Lambda Expression in Include Repository Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I found this Generic Repository but I did found a way to use it:

```
    public T FindSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var set = FindIncluding(includes);

        return (predicate == null) ? set.FirstOrDefault() : set.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
```

How can I call this to include several related entities like this?:

```
        Message messageParentDomain = _messageRepository.FindSingle(m => m.Id == messageDto.MessageParent_Id, includes: i => i.MemberFrom, i => i.MemberTo);
```

Message class:

```
public class Message
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameFrom { get; set; }
    public string EmailFrom { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneFrom { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public bool? Approved { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateRead { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Member MemberFrom { get; set; }
    public Member MemberTo { get; set; }
    public MessageType MessageType { get; set; }
    public Message MessageParent { get; set; }

    public Ad Ad { get; set; }
    public Ask Ask { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it without the "includes:" part? Just letting the `params` part work as normal?

Comment: Hi, Yes but it's not working.

Comment: "It's not working" is not a sufficient description of what's wrong.

Comment: I can't compile, I get always the code underlined

Comment: I suspect you get more than that. I suspect you get an error message from the compiler. These are things you should say *in the question*. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of the method that compiles:

```
public T FindSingle<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    var set = FindIncluding(includes);

    return (predicate == null) ? set.FirstOrDefault() : set.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

I'm assuming that T is called `Message` (you can't pass T) to give us `FindSingle<Message>` and `Expression<Func<Message, object>>`. You need to replace the T with the object you're really using. Try this code ...

```
Message messageParentDomain = 
    _messageRepository.FindSingle<Message>(
        m => m.Id == messageDto.MessageParent_Id, 
        includes: new Expression<Func<Message, object>>[] {
            i => i.MemberFrom,
            i => i.MemberTo
        });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. What do you mean by "You'll need to replace T with the object you're really using" ? I tried Message but I get null for the related entity that I use in the includes

Comment: Does the Message class have any references to other classes? Can you add the Message class to the question?

Comment: Hi, yes I have included it in the question.